# Tree performance and use comparison

Tags: performance, tree, comparison

While studying for a test I was wondering if I could collect all the information into one place. One the test we will need to be able to describe the performance of specific trees (AVL, Red-Black, AA, Splay, B-trees) and also when it would be most practical to use them in a real world scenario. I know all of the running times, most being O log(n), but I am having a difficult time coming up with real-world examples of when to use each. Any thoughts?

Example would be like: B-tree because if you only want to access chunks of memory instead of single bits of memory each time you do an operation, which would be used for slower sources such as a HDD or CD. Reducing the overall time to pull the data from the source.